# Maximum sum of non-contiguous elements of an array

Tags: c

So I was doing this problem on algorithms where I had to find the maximum sum of non-consecutive elements in an array, going for the DP approach. While the sum is easy to obtain, I cannot figure out how to obtain the individual subsolutions (or the numbers which form the maximum sum).

I have tried checking if the element being inserted is an adjacent element or not.

```
int MaxSum(int arr[], int n) {
    int a[n/2];
    int inc = arr[0]; 
    int exc = 0; 
    int exc_n; 
    int i, pos = -1, j = 0; 

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) 
    { 
        if (inc > exc)
        {
            exc_n = inc;
            if (pos + 1 != i){
            a[j] = arr[i];  
            j++;
            pos = i;
        }
        else
        {
            exc_n = exc;
        }
        inc = exc + arr[i]; 
        exc = exc_n; 
    } 

    return ((inc > exc) ? inc : exc); 
}
```

I need to return the elements that form the maximum sum that satisfy the "non-adjacent" condition. What am I doing wrong and what can I do to proceed?

Comment: If you express your solutions as a set of indices, you just have to check that none of those elements are within 1 of each other. If your set is sorted, you can just compare subsequent elements.

Comment: Please reduce the white space in the question's code sample. There is no reason for needing to scroll through the code, it could fit in a single view.

Comment: `int a[n/2];` -- This is not C++.  So which language are you using, C or C++?

Comment: @Francois So basically run a loop and obtain the elements  where a change in value of variable exc is taking place, then remove adjacent elements from them?

Comment: Edited. Please check.

Comment: @ArkadyutiBanerjee My comment was not about finding solutions. It was about verifying the adjacency requirement. It may not even be required, depending on how you choose to generate candidate solutions.

Comment: This code doesn't compile as is.  There's a missing `}` somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to check that @FrançoisAndrieux